# Bill, the Galactic Hero: meaning of the Leg

Tags: bill-the-galactic-hero

Through the series about *Bill, the Galactic Hero*, he gets many different legs and I wonder:

- how many different legs does he... "wear"? "use"?
- does Harrison tear Bill's leg off for some deep reasons or just to make the series more satirical and funny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original book is an anti-war book, parodying Starship Trooper by Heinlein and Foundation by Asimov amongst others. He shoots his foot off to get out of the war zone as there were no replacement feet (His arm was replace earlier in the book). All subsequent books are humorous in the style of the Stainless Steel Rat. I don't know how many he wore.